# Tinymce toolbar config

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to remove certain buttons from the toolbar's dropdowns. For example the default "Format" dropdown has all the heading type(from h1 to h6), but I only need h2 and h3.

I am using Tinymce 4. I managed to find some docs, but they didn't work(they might be for version 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, May be this will help you -->
[Customize tinymce 4.0.5 styleselect toolbar menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699465/customize-tinymce-4-0-5-styleselect-toolbar-menu), Add or remove your necessary buttons...